# Can [ArrayElementType] metadata tag be used on a function parameter

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex4

What language construction can be used to make a compile time checking of Array elements type when the Array is a function parameter?

Let's use this function as an example:

```
[ArrayElementType("String")]
private function GetNumberArray(parameter:Array):Array {
   var myData:Array = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0];
   return myData;
}
```

Here we've marked the returned Array as one containing elements of type string.
Is there a way to mark the `parameter` variable as an Array containing elements of certain type?
I'm specially interested in the Array collection. I'm aware of the vector collection but I have reasons not to use it in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no way to apply the attribute on the parameter. If you try to apply it as shown bellow you'll get compiler error.

```
[ArrayElementType("String")]
private function GetNumberArray(
   [ArrayElementType("String")] 
   parameter:Array):Array
{
   var myData:Array = ["1.0", "2.0", "3.0"];
   return myData;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Flash 10 supports vectors.

Use `Vector.<String>` instead ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Vector](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/Vector.html), although that has a slightly different type than an array:

```
private function GetNumberArray(parameter:Vector.<String>):Vector.<int> {
    var myData:Vector.<int> = Vector.<int>([1.0, 2.0, 3.0]);
    return myData;
}
```